# Tabset in R Markdown creating undefined tabs

Tags: css, r, dplyr

My question boils down to the css code. When I create a sample R markdown document and just create a nonsensical second tab, I get this issue where there are two tabs titled undefined.

The R markdown code and css can be found at https://github.com/twilcox197805/tab_example/blob/main/first

I know that there are two items in the YAML (releasefooter and releaseheader) but I can't give those out. Does anyone know of any sample items i can use in the place of them? When I delete the footer item from the YAML, these undefined tabs go away? Any insights as to why I am getting the undefined tabs would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure why this worked but when I removed the after_body element, the footer, it stopped producing the unidentified duplicate tabs.